# Why navigation dropdown content still shifts when hovered over?

Tags: html, css

Posted something early this morning, but I'm still having issues with the navigation moving whenever the cursor hovers over the item to display the dropdown, instead of both submenus and parent elements not being the same width. I've done what has been suggested, and looked at other examples, but am not able to make both parent and child the same element, let alone having the navegation shift.

```css
/***** whole navigation bar *****/

nav#nav-content {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-faimily: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13.7px;
}

nav#nav-content ul {
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav#nav-content>li {
  width: auto;
  /*selects whole <li> tags under <nav> tag */
  position: absolute;
  /*to provide boundry*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/***** all links *****/

ul#exo-menu a:link
/* all normal, unvisitied links under <ul> */

{
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0E0E10;
  /* jet black */
  color: #FFFAFA;
  /* olde lace */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px 13px;
}

ul#exo-menu a:visited
/* visited link */

{
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  /* white smoke */
  color: #1A1110;
  /* licorice */
}

ul#exo-menu a:hover
/* mouse over link, must come after <a:link> and <a:visited> */

{
  background-color: #242124;
  /* raiden */
  color: #FFFFF0;
  /* ivory */
}

ul#exo-menu a:active
/* a link that's selected - must come after <a:hover> */

{
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  color: #808080;
}


/* disables links */

nav#nav-content div.cursor {
  /* Since pointer-event: none; disables all mouse functions, wrap  disabled link with a div tag, and then add the cursor input.*/
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

nav#nav-content a.disabledLink {
  pointer-events: none;
}


/***** all <button> tags *****/

button.dropbtn {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  background-color: #0E0E10;
  /* jet black */
  color: #FFFAFA;
  /* olde lace white */
  /* width: 100% */
  margin: 0;
  /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  padding: 7px 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

button.dropbtn:hover {
  background-color: #242124;
  /* raiden */
  color: #FFFFF0;
  /* ivory */
}

button.dropbtn:active {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  color: #808080;
}


/***** submenu positioning *****/

ul .dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#exo-menu ul {
  background-color: #0E0E10;
  /* jet black */
  /* Adding a background makes the dropdown work properly in IE7+. Make this as close to your page's background as possible (i.e. white page == white background). */
  color: #FFFAFA;
  /* olde lace */
  /* position: absolute; */
  display: none;
  left: -9999px;
  /* Hide off-screen when not needed (this is more accessible than display: none;) */
}

#exo-menu>li:hover>ul {
  /*to keep it under relative li*/
  /* position: absolute; */
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  /* Bring back on-screen when needed */
  background: #fff;
  /* border: 1px solid #000; */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-content">
  <ul id="exo-menu">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">The Desi Ghost Hunters
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
            </button>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="suboption"><a href="#" title="Siddharth Bantval">Siddharth Bantval</a></li>
        <li class="suboption"><a href="https://www.ikerjimenez.com/" target="_blank" title="REAL NAME: Iker Jiménez Elizari">Iker Jiménez</a></li>
        <li class="suboption"><a href="#" title="Gaurav Tiwari">Gaurav Tiwari <span class="cross">&#8225;</span></a></li>
        <li class="suboption"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5RfSq8MS00LWofLPSKAnDA" target="_blank" title="Alberto del Arco">Alberto del Arco</a></li>
        <li class="suboption"><a href="#" title="Alexsander Myagchenkov">Alexsander Myagchenkov</a></li>
        <li class="suboption"><a href="http://chernobrov.narod.ru/" target="_blank" title="Vadim Chernobrov">Vadim Chernobrov <span class="cross">&#8225;</span></li>
                <li class="suboption"><a href="#" title="Meghna Porwal">Meghna Porwal</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn  main-btn" aria-expanded="false" title="N">Cazafantasmas españoles
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
            </button>
      <ul class="submenu" id="multiple">
        <li class="nest">
          <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn country">Spain
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
                    </button>
          <ul class="sub-submenu">
            <li class="sub-suboption"><a href="https://www.ikerjimenez.com/" target="_blank" title="REAL NAME: Iker Jiménez Elizari">Iker Jiménez</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nest">
          <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn country">Mexico
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
                    </button>
          <ul class="sub-submenu">
            <li class="sub-suboption"><a href="#" title="Octavio Elizondo">Octavio Elizondo</a></li>
            <li class="sub-suboption"><a href="#" title="Luisa Cárdenas">Luisa Cárdenas</a></li>
            <li class="sub-suboption"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5RfSq8MS00LWofLPSKAnDA" target="_blank" title="Alberto del Arco">Alberto del Arco</a></li>
            <li class="sub-suboption"><a href="#" title="Silvia Enciso">Silvia Enciso</a></li>
            <li class="sub-suboption"><a href="#" title="Laura Rivas">Laura Rivas</a></li>
            <li class="sub-suboption"><a href="#" title="Miriam Verdecía">Miriam Verdecía</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown mega">
      <button type="button" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder0&#39;);" class="dropbtn main" aria-expanded="false">Guest Appearances
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
            </button>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="option">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
              <a href="#">Pavlína Pořízková</a>
              <a href="#">María Rosario Pilar Martínez Molina Baeza</a>
              <a href="#">Kofi Nahaje Sarkodie-Mensah </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responcse, but is there a way to make the navigation not scrunch up the submenu?

Answer (score 1):

You can make each sub-menu `position:absolute` if the dropdown is `position:relative` and you remove the `overflow:hidden`.

```css
/***** whole navigation bar *****/

nav#nav-content {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-faimily: "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13.7px;
}

nav#nav-content ul {
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav#nav-content>li {
  width: auto;
  /*selects whole <li> tags under <nav> tag */
  position: absolute;
  /*to provide boundry*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/***** all links *****/

ul#exo-menu a:link
/* all normal, unvisitied links under <ul> */

{
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0E0E10;
  /* jet black */
  color: #FFFAFA;
  /* olde lace */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px 13px;
}

ul#exo-menu a:visited
/* visited link */

{
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  /* white smoke */
  color: #1A1110;
  /* licorice */
}

ul#exo-menu a:hover
/* mouse over link, must come after <a:link> and <a:visited> */

{
  background-color: #242124;
  /* raiden */
  color: #FFFFF0;
  /* ivory */
}

ul#exo-menu a:active
/* a link that's selected - must come after <a:hover> */

{
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  color: #808080;
}


/* disables links */

nav#nav-content div.cursor {
  /* Since pointer-event: none; disables all mouse functions, wrap  disabled link with a div tag, and then add the cursor input.*/
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

nav#nav-content a.disabledLink {
  pointer-events: none;
}


/***** all <button> tags *****/

button.dropbtn {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  background-color: #0E0E10;
  /* jet black */
  color: #FFFAFA;
  /* olde lace white */
  /* width: 100% */
  margin: 0;
  /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  padding: 7px 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  //margin: 0 5px;
}

button.dropbtn:hover {
  background-color: #242124;
  /* raiden */
  color: #FFFFF0;
  /* ivory */
}

button.dropbtn:active {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  color: #808080;
}


/***** submenu positioning *****/

ul .dropdown {
  float: left;
  //overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#exo-menu ul {
  background-color: #0E0E10;
  /* jet black */
  /* Adding a background makes the dropdown work properly in IE7+. Make this as close to your page's background as possible (i.e. white page == white background). */
  color: #FFFAFA;
  /* olde lace */
  /* position: absolute; */
  display: none;
  left: -9999px;
  /* Hide off-screen when not needed (this is more accessible than display: none;) */
}

#exo-menu>li>ul button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#exo-menu>li:hover>ul {
  /*to keep it under relative li*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* Bring back on-screen when needed */
  background: #fff;
  /* border: 1px solid #000; */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-content">
  <ul id="exo-menu">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">The Desi Ghost Hunters
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
            </button>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="suboption"><a href="#" title="Siddharth Bantval">Siddharth Bantval</a></li>
        <li class="suboption"><a href="https://www.ikerjimenez.com/" target="_blank" title="REAL NAME: Iker Jiménez Elizari">Iker Jiménez</a></li>
        <li class="suboption"><a href="#" title="Gaurav Tiwari">Gaurav Tiwari <span class="cross">&#8225;</span></a></li>
        <li class="suboption"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5RfSq8MS00LWofLPSKAnDA" target="_blank" title="Alberto del Arco">Alberto del Arco</a></li>
        <li class="suboption"><a href="#" title="Alexsander Myagchenkov">Alexsander Myagchenkov</a></li>
        <li class="suboption"><a href="http://chernobrov.narod.ru/" target="_blank" title="Vadim Chernobrov">Vadim Chernobrov <span class="cross">&#8225;</span></li>
                <li class="suboption"><a href="#" title="Meghna Porwal">Meghna Porwal</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn  main-btn" aria-expanded="false" title="N">Cazafantasmas españoles
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
            </button>
      <ul class="submenu" id="multiple">
        <li class="nest">
          <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn country">Spain
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
                    </button>
          <ul class="sub-submenu">
            <li class="sub-suboption"><a href="https://www.ikerjimenez.com/" target="_blank" title="REAL NAME: Iker Jiménez Elizari">Iker Jiménez</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nest">
          <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn country">Mexico
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
                    </button>
          <ul class="sub-submenu">
            <li class="sub-suboption"><a href="#" title="Octavio Elizondo">Octavio Elizondo</a></li>
            <li class="sub-suboption"><a href="#" title="Luisa Cárdenas">Luisa Cárdenas</a></li>
            <li class="sub-suboption"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5RfSq8MS00LWofLPSKAnDA" target="_blank" title="Alberto del Arco">Alberto del Arco</a></li>
            <li class="sub-suboption"><a href="#" title="Silvia Enciso">Silvia Enciso</a></li>
            <li class="sub-suboption"><a href="#" title="Laura Rivas">Laura Rivas</a></li>
            <li class="sub-suboption"><a href="#" title="Miriam Verdecía">Miriam Verdecía</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown mega">
      <button type="button" onclick="togglefolder(&#39;folder0&#39;);" class="dropbtn main" aria-expanded="false">Guest Appearances
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
            </button>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="option">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
              <a href="#">Pavlína Pořízková</a>
              <a href="#">María Rosario Pilar Martínez Molina Baeza</a>
              <a href="#">Kofi Nahaje Sarkodie-Mensah </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```